# Case sensitivity in shell scripting

Tags: bash, scripts

Consider this Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Enter any character
read char
case $char in
    [a-z]) echo Lower case letter
            ;;
    [A-Z]) echo Upper case letter
            ;;
    [0-9]) echo Number
            ;;
    ?) echo Special char
            ;;
    *) echo You entered more than one character 
            ;;
esac
```

If I enter 'a', the output is *Lower case letter*, and it is the same for 'A'... How do I overcome this?

Comment: When you post a script make sure you use the code format, to keep the whitespace. Also, what's the actual question? I'm not sure what you mean...

Comment: @Arronical no need, echo can deal with reserved words `echo if case then do` .

Comment: For a similar issue, but dealing with sort, see http://askubuntu.com/questions/597924/wrong-behavior-of-sort-command?newsletter=1&nlcode=17739|f2f3

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'enter any character'
read char
case $char in
[[:lower:]]) echo 'lower case letter'
    ;;
[[:upper:]]) echo 'upper case letter'
    ;;
[0-9]) echo 'number'
    ;;
?) echo 'special char'
    ;;
*) echo 'u entered more than one char' 
    ;;
esac
```

For more information about the lower case regular expression of **[a-z]** and the  upper case regular expression of **[A-Z]** in bash see [Why isn't the case statement case-sensitive when nocasematch is off?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10695029/why-isnt-the-case-statement-case-sensitive-when-nocasematch-is-off).

Comment: Following on from this, instead of `[0-9]` you can use `[[:digit:]]`. You can find more examples in `man grep`, or Google **posix character classes**.

Answer (score 21):

The problem is that the character range `[a-z]` actually includes the upper case letters. This is explained in the [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions.html):

> Within a bracket expression, a range expression consists of two characters separated by a hyphen. It matches any single character that sorts between the two characters, inclusive. **In the default C locale, the sorting sequence is the native character order; for example, ‘[a-d]’ is equivalent to ‘[abcd]’. In other locales, the sorting sequence is not specified, and ‘[a-d]’ might be equivalent to ‘[abcd]’ or to ‘[aBbCcDd]’**, or it might fail to match any character, or the set of characters that it matches might even be erratic. To obtain the traditional interpretation of bracket expressions, you can use the ‘C’ locale by setting the LC_ALL environment variable to the value ‘C’.

To illustrate:

```
$ case B in [a-c]) echo YES;;  *) echo NO;; esac
YES
$ LC_ALL=C; case B in [a-c]) echo YES;; *) echo NO;; esac
NO
```

So, what happens is that in your locale (which is not `C`), `[a-c]` is actually `[aAbBcC]`. That's why you should use the POSIX character classes [as suggested](https://askubuntu.com/a/596321/85695) by @karel instead.

Comment: More precisely, you need to set `LC_COLLATE` to `C`, it's ok for other locale settings to be different. Setting `LC_COLLATE` to anything but `C` is rarely a good idea but sadly Ubuntu does it (it isn't the only culprit by far).