# Wrong behavior of sort command?

Tags: command-line, sort

I tried to sort the content of a file in [Ubuntu desktop 14.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_14.04_LTS_.28Trusty_Tahr.29) (Trusty Tahr). In my case, the expected result should be same as original content, but the actual result is not. Why?

```
# cat test.txt
a++-a
a++-b
a++-c
ab
ac
```

```
# cat test.txt | sort
a++-a
ab
a++-b
ac
a++-c
```

Comment: I hand you a small award trophy for your [useless use of `cat`](http://www.smallo.ruhr.de/award.html#cat).

Comment: The comment of @DavidFoerster is a funny way of pointing out that you can replace `cat test.txt | sort` by `sort test.txt` :)

Comment: @VolkerSiegel: True, though there are useful formulations using `cat` to start. For example `cat FILE | grep dev | sort` will display only lines with "dev" in them (in sorted order). Using `sort FILE | grep dev` produces the same output but coloured.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could use `LC_ALL` variable, set it to `LC_ALL=C` before calling `sort`

```
$ LC_ALL=C sort test.txt
a++-a
a++-b
a++-c
ab
ac
```

Read [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/87763/55273) answer, if you want to know what is this magically `LC_ALL=C`. Here is short summary:

> The C locale is a special locale that is meant to be the simplest locale. You could also say that while the other locales are for humans, the C locale is for computers. In the C locale, characters are single bytes, the charset is ASCII, the sorting order is based on the byte values.

Also, as @KenMollerup pointed, quote from `man sort`

```
   ***  WARNING  ***  The locale specified by the environment affects sort
   order.  Set LC_ALL=C to get the traditional sort order that uses native
   byte values.
```

So when using sort with `LC_ALL=C`, sort compare symbols bytewise. Otherwise `sort` will ignore all non alphanumerical characters.

Comment: Sorry didnt see this, I reacted to the comment!

Comment: @KenMollerup thanks for pointing to `man sort`. I didn't notice it

Answer (score 8):

Sort uses alphabetical and numeric sorting, same as us, special characters like + - < > ... are ignored, numbers are treated numerical so 1, 2, 3..  comes before 11, 12 1066 1104 -- see!

So your list is seen as: aa,  ab, ab, ac, ac

Comment: Is there any option for sort, such that it will not ignore special characters such that test.txt will sort the desired way?

Comment: See this in man sort:
 ***  WARNING  ***  The locale specified by the environment affects sort order.  Set LC_ALL=C to get the traditional sort order that uses native byte values.

Comment: @KenMollerup, please add more information to your answer. Add quote from `man sort`, add examples.

Comment: Yes but I was tooo slow, see c0rp's answer below.